# Saving a flat-file through Vim add an invisible byte to the file that creates a new line

Tags: linux, vim, character-encoding, diff, flat-file

*The title is not really specific, but I have trouble identifying the correct key words as I'm not sure what is going on here. For the same reason, it is possible that my question has a duplicate, as . If that's the case: sorry!*

I have a Linux application that receive data via flat files. I don't know exactly how those files are generated, but I can read them without any problem. Those are short files, only a line each.

For test purpose, I tried to modify one of those files and reinjected it again in the application. But when I do that I can see in the log that it added a mysterious page break at the end of the message (resulting in the application not recognising the message)...

For the sake of example, let's say I receive a flat file, named *original*, that contains the following:

```
ABCDEF
```

I make a copy of this file and named it *copy*.

- If I compare those two files using the "diff" command, it says they are identical (as I expect them to be)
- If I open *copy* via Vi and then quit without changing nor saving anything and then use the "diff" command, it says they are identical (as I also expect them to be)
- If I open *copy* via Vi and then save it without changing anything and then use the "diff" command, I have the following (I added the dot for layout purpose):

`diff original copy
    1c1
    < ABCDEF
    \ No newline at end of file
    ---
   .> ABCDEF`

And if I compare the size of my two files, I can see that *original* is 71 bytes when *copy* is 72.

It seems that the format of the file change when I save the file. I first thought of an encoding problem, so I used the ":set list" command on Vim to see the invisible characters. But for both files, I can see the following:

```
ABCDEF$
```

I have found other ways to do my test, But this problem still bugged me and I would really like to understand it. So, my two questions are:

1. What is happening here?
2. How can I modify a file like that without creating this mysterious page break?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `vi` is a line editor.  If the file does not end on a newline (`\n`, ASCII 10), then the `vi` appends one.  That's your one additional byte.  If you do not like that, use a different editor, e. g. Emacs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What happens is that Vim is set by default to assume that the files you edit end with a "newline" character. That's *normal* behavior in UNIX-land. But the "files" your program is reading look more like "streams" to me because they don't end with a newline character.

To ensure that those "files" are written without a newline character, set the following options before writing:

```
:set binary noeol
```

See `:help 'eol'`.

Comment: With `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Jun 14 2016 16:06:49)
` on a Mac, I find that the correct options are: `:set binary noendofline` and that `:set binary noeol` has no effect.